# Неоднородные дополнения с общим вопросом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, подчинительная-связь

Есть предложение:

> О чём я только не писала: о деревьях, о людях, о котах, и были даже
>   тексты про африканские племена.

Теперь вопрос: присоединяется оборот "и были...", и формат у него другой, не такой, как у однородных дополнений до него. В то же время это всё объединено одним пояснением ("о чём я только не писала"), одной подчинительной связью, то есть запятая вроде бы не нужна.

Нужна или не нужна запятая перед "и"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна.

Этот случай сопоставим с правилом расчленения составного союза. Если есть однородные элементы, то союз расчленяется:
*Перед зАвтраком, перед Ужином, перед тЕм, как поесть, он пьёт воду.*

Подобно этому, ударения способствуют расчленению сообщённых фрагментов:
*О чём я только не писала: о дерЕвьях, о лЮдях, о кот**А**х, и были даже тЕксты про африканские племенА.* || Из-за однородных ударений часть после двоеточия не читается в одну фразу. Без выделенного ударения, которое способствует наличию запятой, не читается.

Вдобавок к этому у части с И интонация присоединительная. Предложение будто заменяет однородный элемент "*о африканских племенах*".

Answer (score 2):

А почему **"и были даже тексты про африканские племена"** - это оборот? Это полноправное предложение: *тексты были*.

Сложносочинённое предложение, запятая перед И нужна.

Comment: Когда есть общий второстепенный член или целая часть, к которой всё это прикручено подчинительной связью, запятая не нужна. В этом и вопрос.

Comment: Да нет здесь общего члена: О чём я только не писала (...), и были даже тексты про африканские племена. Однородные члены всего лишь распространяют обобщающий член "о чём".

Answer (score 1):

(1) ***О чём*** я только не писала: **о деревьях, о людях, о котах**, (2) и были (у меня) даже тексты про африканские племена.

Интересно, а грамматический разбор предложения для объяснения знаков препинания уже не надо делать?

А давайте попробуем.

**Это ССП, состоит из двух предложений.** Первое предложение осложнено обособленным однородным рядом, раскрывающим содержание местоимения **о чем** (оно здесь в роли обобщающего слова).  Двоеточие как раз и ставится перед однородным рядом. Кстати, там и тире можно поставить. Запятая перед И ставится между двумя предложениями по обычному правилу (**при отсутствии общих элементов**).

Конечно, общая тема связывает эти два предложения, поэтому во втором  подразумевается местоимение ***у меня***. Но нет у них общего дополнения, обстоятельства,  вводного слова, и даже общей бессоюзной связи тоже нет.  Это только кажется, что она есть. И **соединить однородный ряд с целым предложением** с помощью союза И довольно проблематично

**Но не все так думают.**

Цитирую: *Когда есть общий второстепенный член или целая часть, к которой всё это прикручено подчинительной связью, запятая не нужна. В этом и вопрос.* – Анастасия Спивак вчера.

И где же тут **подчинительная связь, где общий член, к которому всё прикручено?** Если однородный ряд куда-то и прикручен, то к первому предложению, а далее следует вполне самостоятельное второе предложение.

Дальше больше. Теперь уже в ответе появляются: **расчлененные составные союзы** (вроде бы их там нет), **сообщенные фрагменты** (а это что?), расставляются **однородные ударения** (вот уж никогда о таких не слышала). Терминология – вещь строгая, серьезная, не стоит с ней обращаться слишком свободно.

Тем не менее **таинственно звучащий ответ принимается как верный**. И пусть oleedd на меня за критику не обижается (почему-то я ему всё равно симпатизирую), но всё-таки  пройти мимо и не дать должную оценку **ВСЕМУ ЭТОМУ** просто невозможно.

Comment: Ну что вы всё придираетесь, ничего не спрашивая и не уточняя (я так не делаю, сначала спрашиваю, если мне что-то неясно). Просто провёл аналогию: тут происходит похожее, как с составными союзами. Впервые с таким столкнулся и заметил сходство. Однородные ударения - условно про ударения на однородных существительных. Сообщённые фрагменты - те, которые объединены чем-то общим. С этим сочетанием пришлось долго повозится, копаясь в словарях. Если знаете, чем заменить, сохраняя такой смысл, то мне очень интересно.

Comment: Почему я придираюсь? В этом вопросе изначально было заложено неверное понимание грамматики - ну ничего общего с действительностью. Там нет практически ни одного правильного слова: предложение названо оборотом, найдена неизвестная подчинительная связь и т.д.  Начало у вас хорошее: Запятая нужна. А дальше вы должны перейти к грамматическому анализу, который автор вопроса истолковал совершенно неверно. Почитайте ответ Людмилы, он хотя и кратко, но  верно объясняет причину постановки запятой. А у вас нет объяснения вообще. Вы рассказываете историю, которая не имеет отношения к теме.

Comment: И про однородные ударения. Можно так (условно и в кавычках) назвать ударение на однородных членах, и это правильно. Да только слово "тексты" в однородный ряд не входит, а второе самостоятельное предложение не является фрагментом. И где же вы нашли эти "сообщенные фрагменты" - именно при анализе русской грамматики? Вот это действительно любопытно. Так что не придираюсь я к вам, а просто поправляю (корректно и ненавязчиво).  Вы нашли для себя что-то интересное? Прекрасно! Но как говорится, слона-то вы и не заметили. То есть прошли мимо элементарного грамматического анализа, увлеклись фантазиями.

Comment: "*А дальше вы должны...*" — почему же должен? Каждый отвечает по-своему. "Фрагмент" использовал, чтобы не повторять много раз слово "часть". "О чём" действительно связано по смыслу с частью после И. Я бы не воспринял грамматику (самый лёгкий подход) как абсолютное доказательство на месте автора вопроса, поэтому решил действовать по-другому. Если бы условно не было ряда, то и запятой тоже: *О чём я только не писала: о деревьях и были тексты про африканские племена.*

Comment: Там не чаСть, не фрагмент, а самостоятельное предложение, вполне распространенное. Оба предложения входят в состав сложного целого, как тут не быть чего-то общего. Различайте семантику и форму. И избегайте сослагательного наклонения. Вот перед вами реальное предложение. Его форма определяется однозначно: это ССП, однородный ряд и обобщающее слово относится ТОЛЬКО к первому предложению.  Поэтому НЕТ ОБЩЕГО ЭЛЕМЕНТА, запятая ставится. Да или нет? Дайте честный ответ.

Comment: Фрагмент сложного предложения, если хотите. Этим словом просто ссылаюсь на кусок текста. А после И распространяется мысль до двоеточия. Какой честный ответ? В ответе же сказал, что ставится.

Comment: Честного ответа не вижу, одни отмазки. Вас так в школе учили делать грамматический разбор? Не просто  предложение, не его предикативная основа, а фрагмент? А мысль, она конечно, где-то там распространяется, но только не в грамматике. Потому что грамматика - это форма предложения, его модель.  Различайте форму и  содержание - оно всегда пригодится. Запятые ж ставятся по интонационно-грамматическому принципу, причем правила ориентированы преимущественно на грамматический. Так что определяйте грамматику, ищите правило, корректируйте по интонации, если нужно. В данном случае этого не требовалось.

Comment: Не ругайтесь) С оборотом я накосячила, согласна. Суть не в этом. Меня тут как раз интересует то, что части лексически однородны, схожи по смыслу (последнюю часть можно заменить на короткое "об африканских племенах"). И именно этот момент меня смущает. Грамматически тут действительно всё однозначно: присоединено простое предложение, никаких вопросов. Но по смыслу это схоже с однородным перечислением.

Comment: Всё дело в том, что для  одного  и того же содержания можно подобрать разные формы, при этом каждая будет оформляться по своим правилам. Как только мы хотя бы что-то меняем, то меняется и форма, и это уже будет другое предложение. Можно переделать текст (для сравнения): О чём  только не приходилось писать:  я рассказывала о деревьях, о людях, о котах и были даже тексты про африканские племена. Здесь действительно общая часть и нет запятых.